# Iterator that assigns subvalue as key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, iterator, ogd-wien

Currently I'm looping through a quite large data set. This multidimensional array needs to be grouped by specific array values of its sub arrays. As this is a holiday project, I want to do deepen my knowledge and make more use of PHPs Iterators. Point is, that I don't know how to transform a numeric multi-dimensional Array into a multi-dimensional array with associative keys.

Shortened example (GeoJSON to Array)

```
array (size=4)
  'type' => string 'FeatureCollection' (length=17)
  'features' => // THIS is the actual array
    array (size=207)
      0 => // Sub-Arrays like this one are repeating
        array (size=5)
          'type' => string 'Feature' (length=7)
          'geometry' => 
            array (size=2)
              'type' => string 'LineString' (length=10)
              'coordinates' => 
                array (size=410)
                  0 => 
                    array (size=2)
                      0 => float 16.359980888872
                      1 => float 48.208437070943
                  // etc.
      'geometry_name' => string 'SHAPE' (length=5)
      'properties' => 
        array (size=5)
          'OBJECTID'         => int 273
          // This/"LBEZEICHNUNG" is the part I want to order/summon
          // all further "geometry"-parts by
          'LBEZEICHNUNG'     => string '13A, 2, 86, U3' (length=1)
          'LTYP'             => string '1' (length=1)
          'LTYPTXT'          => string 'Tramway' (length=12)
          'SE_ANNO_CAD_DATA' => null
      'id' => int 1
```

The `features` array is what holds the actually looped datasets. And `LBEZEICHNUNG` are the values (single or comma separated) I want to sort/order by.

To make an example:

```
// Original values:
'LBEZEICHNUNG' => string '13A, 2, 86, U3'

// Now split them and push the features into new keys that have those values:
'13A' => array(
  0 => // Sub-Arrays like this one are repeating
    array (size=5)
      'type' => string 'Feature' (length=7)
      'geometry' => 
        array (size=2)
          'type' => string 'LineString' (length=10)
          'coordinates' => 
            array (size=410)
              0 => 
                array (size=2)
                  0 => float 16.359980888872
                  1 => float 48.208437070943
              // etc.
  'geometry_name' => string 'SHAPE' (length=5)
  'properties' => 
    array (size=5)
      // "OBJECTID" now is obsolete
      // "LBEZEICHNUNG" is now obsolete
      'LTYP'             => string '1' (length=1)
      'LTYPTXT'          => string 'Tramway' (length=12)
      'SE_ANNO_CAD_DATA' => null
   // "id" now is obsolete as well
),
"2" => // gets the same values as "13A"
// same goes for "86" and "U3"
```

Now every sub array that would have either `13A`, `2`, `86` or `U3` in `["properties"]["LBEZEICHNUNG"]`, would push its `geometry` to the end of the already existing subarray/sub-Iterator.

So far I only got a basic recursive Iterator set up, that runs through all leaves.

```
$data = new \RecursiveArrayIterator( $fileContents );
foreach( new \RecursiveIteratorIterator( $data ) as $key => $value )
{
    // foo. bar. dragons.
}
```

Point is that I can't really figure out how to assign new keys from values in the Iterator. I already tried using a `RecursiveFilterIterator` and failed gracefully as its simply not intended to do this. Quite frankly: I'm lost as I either can't find the right Iterator to use or I simply ain't know enough about Iterators yet.

I got a working solution with nested foreach-es pushing into another Array. As this is my holiday project I want to learn, hence the Iterator solution, which I hope is more maintainable in the long turn.

*Edit:* [Link to the original Geo-JSON data set](http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json&typeName=ogdwien%3aOEFFLINIENOGD) <sup>CC-BY-SA 3.0/AUT - Data provided by the City of Vienna</sup>. Other formats can be [found here](https://open.wien.at/site/datensatz/?id=36a8b9e9-909e-4605-a7ba-686ee3e1b8bf).

Comment: Can you provide us with the array string or GeoJSON data that could be used for testing purposes?

Comment: @MohammadReza Sure. See the edit and the added links at the end of the question.

Comment: One more question, `'LBEZEICHNUNG'     => string '13A, 2, 86, U3'` has alphanumerical characters in it. Based on what sorting strategy of LBEZEICHNUNG values are you going to sort each "feature" sub-array? Digits? Are you gonna use the first item "13A"?

Comment: As stated in the other comment, I want to group/order them by this values. So splitting that string and assigning this array to each of those four keys. Didn't explain it too well (sorry).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to sort/ or group the array based on that "LBEZEICHNUNG" key, and use PHP iterators. In order to do that, you have to traverse the entire array, and build a new one that holds the values grouped by that key. This is simple `foreach` logic.

Iterators shine when you want to traverse a data collection and fetch the data during traversal (or alter it).

In this case, you are fetching the data outside of the iterator (`json_decode` ?), so that makes iterators kind of pointless - unless you need to do more than just sorting. If you do, I'd suggest you store that data in a format that allows you to easily fetch sorted sets, like a database, then you can use iterators to their full potential.

---

One way to group the routes is to use basic OOP:

```
class Route{
  protected $trams = array();
  // add other route properties (type, geometry etc.)

  public function assignTo(Tram $line){
   if(!in_array($line, $this->trams, true))
     $this->trams[] = $line;
  }

  public function getTrams(){
    return $this->trams;
  }
}

class Tram{
  public $name;
  protected $routes = array();

  public function __construct($name){
    $this->name= $name;
  }

  public function addRoute(Route $route){
    $this->routes[] = $route;
    $route->assignTo($this);
  }

  public function getRoutes(){
    return $this->routes;
  }
}
```

Example:

```
$trams = array();
foreach($data as $routeData){
  $route = new Route();
  $tramNames = explode(', ', $routeData['features']['properties']['LBEZEICHNUNG']);

  foreach($tramNames as $name){
    if(!isset($trams[$name]))
      $trams[$name] = new Tram($name);

    $trams[$name]->addRoute($route);
    // set other route properties...
  }    

}
```

Comment: I get your point. The data comes from the original source (link at the end of the question) and the stage I'm asking about is exactly the preparation _for_ the database. It's public transport lines that are grouped together and I need to split them apart and summon all parts of a route under one key (name/nr of the line) and then save that in a row (or a whole table). So it's not only changing keys and moving the `geometry` parts together, but it's as well reducing the `properties` to what's needed.

Comment: So what you have there is an array of routes, and the "LBEZEICHNUNG" keys represent the name of the vehicles that follow that route?

Comment: Yes, the `LEBEZEICHNUNG`-keys represent the name of the public transport lines. Every sub-array is part of a route. And as some lines share parts of a route they sometimes get stuffed together. I need to group those route parts into single (complete) routes. Therefore I need to take such shared routes and assign them (push to lat/lng stack of that route) to each of the routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use usort to sort your multi-dimensional array based on sub-values:

```
$JSON = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode(file_get_contents("http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json&typeName=ogdwien:OEFFLINIENOGD")));
$geoarray = json_decode($JSON, true);
$myarray = $geoarray["features"];

function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $a["properties"]["LBEZEICHNUNG"] - $b["properties"]["LBEZEICHNUNG"];
}
usort($myarray, "cmp");

print_r($myarray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Mohammad. Seems like I explained badly what I wanted to achieve. Basically I want to reassign those sub arrays to new (alphanumeric) keys, transforming the numeric array into an associative one. I edited the question to clarify things. Also I want to use the StandardPHPLibrary (SPL) Iterators for learning purpose.